# Flink Side output for Sliding time window

Tags: apache-flink, watermark

I have the following Flink pipeline which simply counts the elements in a window and reports on a separate stream the late elements

```
OutputTag<Tuple3<Long, String, Double>> lateItems= new OutputTag<Tuple3<Long, String, Double>>("Late Items"){};
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

env.setParallelism(1);
env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(-1);
DataStream<Tuple3<Long,String,Double>> stream = env.addSource(new  YetAnotherSource(fileName));
DataStream<Tuple3<Long,String,Double>> lateStream;
AllWindowedStream<Tuple3<Long, String, Double>, TimeWindow> tuple3TimeWindowAllWindowedStream = stream.windowAll(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(100), Time.milliseconds(10)));
tuple3TimeWindowAllWindowedStream.sideOutputLateData(lateItems);
lateStream = streamOfResults.getSideOutput(lateItems);
            lateStream.countWindowAll(1).apply(new CounterFunction22()).writeAsText("FlinkSlidingTimeWindowLateItemsResult.txt",FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE);
streamOfResults.writeAsText("FlinkSlidingTimeWindowOutputFor" + fileName + ".txt", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE);
```

When I pass as input the following data

```
1383451269002,A,22
1383451269006,A,18
1383451269007,A,18
*1383451269010,W,0
1383451269008,A,18
1383451269027,A,20
1383451269028,A,19
1383451269033,A,17
1383451269033,A,17
1383451269030,A,17
*1383451269038,W,0
1383451269008,A,17
```

The elements with * are watermarks.

I get as expected as a result the first window contains three elements. That is because the elements on the fifth and the last rows are considered late for that window.

```
(1383451268910,1383451269010,3)
```

However, on the side output nothing is generated.

When I use a session window, though, late items are generated on the side output.

Any ideas why nothing is generated for sliding time window?

Comment: I can't explain why you're not seeing any late events for the sliding window, but I am distracted by setAutoWatermarkInterval(-1), whose behavior is undefined, I believe, and also by the lack of any visible watermark generator.

Comment: I set that to -1 just to disable watermark generation. I was expecting that no output to be generated as all windows will be waiting for the watermark. However, outputs were generated.